# Fast array manipulation based on element inclusion in binary matrix

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

For a large set of randomly distributed points in a 2D lattice, I want to efficiently extract a subarray, which contains only the elements that, approximated as indices, are assigned to non-zero values in a separate 2D binary matrix. Currently, my script is the following:

```
lat_len = 100 # lattice length
input = np.random.random(size=(1000,2)) * lat_len
binary_matrix = np.random.choice(2, lat_len * lat_len).reshape(lat_len, -1)

def landed(input):
    output = []
    input_as_indices = np.floor(input)
    for i in range(len(input)):
        if binary_matrix[input_as_indices[i,0], input_as_indices[i,1]] == 1:
            output.append(input[i])
    output = np.asarray(output)
    return output
```

However, I suspect there must be a better way of doing this. The above script can take quite long to run for 10000 iterations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. The calculation above, can be be done more efficiently without a for loop in python using [advanced numpy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing),

```
def landed2(input):
    idx = np.floor(input).astype(np.int)
    mask = binary_matrix[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]] == 1
    return input[mask]

res1 = landed(input)
res2 = landed2(input)
np.testing.assert_allclose(res1, res2)
```

this results in a ~150x speed-up.

Comment: Incredible. Can you explain what change made the most difference in performance, e.g., the use of int?

Comment: The difference in performance is due to the fact that we avoid the for loop in python, and use advanced numpy indexing instead (I added a link above) that is coded more efficiently in C. Casting to integers is only a side effect, since indexes can't have a float `dtype` and must be either integers or boolean.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you can squeeze in a noticeable performance boost if you work with linearly indexed arrays. Here's a vectorized implementation to solve our case, similar to [@rth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30968630/3293881), but using linear indexing -

```
# Get floor-ed indices
idx = np.floor(input).astype(np.int)

# Calculate linear indices 
lin_idx = idx[:,0]*lat_len + idx[:,1]

# Index raveled/flattened version of binary_matrix with lin_idx
# to extract and form the desired output
out = input[binary_matrix.ravel()[lin_idx] ==1]
```

Thus, in short we have:

```
out = input[binary_matrix.ravel()[idx[:,0]*lat_len + idx[:,1]] ==1]
```

Runtime tests -

This section compares the proposed approach in this solution against the [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30968630/3293881) that uses row-column indexing.

Case #1(Original datasizes):

```
In [62]: lat_len = 100 # lattice length
    ...: input = np.random.random(size=(1000,2)) * lat_len
    ...: binary_matrix = np.random.choice(2, lat_len * lat_len).
                                             reshape(lat_len, -1)
    ...: 

In [63]: idx = np.floor(input).astype(np.int)

In [64]: %timeit input[binary_matrix[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]] == 1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 121 µs per loop

In [65]: %timeit input[binary_matrix.ravel()[idx[:,0]*lat_len + idx[:,1]] ==1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 103 µs per loop
```

Case #2(Larger datasizes):

```
In [75]: lat_len = 1000 # lattice length
    ...: input = np.random.random(size=(100000,2)) * lat_len
    ...: binary_matrix = np.random.choice(2, lat_len * lat_len).
                                             reshape(lat_len, -1)
    ...: 

In [76]: idx = np.floor(input).astype(np.int)

In [77]: %timeit input[binary_matrix[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]] == 1]
100 loops, best of 3: 18.5 ms per loop

In [78]: %timeit input[binary_matrix.ravel()[idx[:,0]*lat_len + idx[:,1]] ==1]
100 loops, best of 3: 13.1 ms per loop
```

Thus, the performance boost with this linear indexing seems to be about **`20%`** - **`30%`**.

Comment: When you're not busy answering `numpy` questions, come visit us in the MATLAB chat room :) We miss you! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab

Comment: @rayryeng Nice place for MATLABans! Oops! I didn't mean "Bans" , meant more like MATLAB people! I guess I will come back when there are more people in there :)

Comment: MATLABians :) ok I'll see you there eventually!